# Adding an element before a row but outside the table?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, jqgrid

I have a table (jqGrid) and I'd like to add a small icon/image before a row dynamically on document load. The image will be inserted based on one of the grid's hidden column values (date); it is supposed to mark the importance/urgency of the row to the page/grid viewer. I'm well versed with jQuery and I have the logic down but the only thing I'm having trouble with is where in the DOM structure this element should be inserted because it shouldn't be part of the actual grid. It should float just to the left of the row outside the grid. So basically, what I'm asking is this:

1) Where in the DOM structure should this element be inserted? The div container containing the actual table?;

2) How should it be styled (CSS)?

The only approach I've come up with is to get the y-coordinate of the row in question and insert it in the div container (that contains the table) set to that y-coordinate. I'm not sure if this is the best or right way to go about it.

**EDIT:** Lots of good approaches here. I'm thinking of combining the "afterInsertRow" event with David's approach. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: It sounds like there should be a column for representing "status" or "importance" (or however you would like to label it) that contains your icon.  Icon or not, it is still part of the tabular dataset.  If the icon must be displayed outside the table, CSS can put it there by changing the display type of the `td` and moving it via absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why add any elements to the outside of the `table`? Just use hidden cells to contain the image/element you want to show and style in response to the `:hover` of the parent `tr`, given the mark-up:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Column 'one'</th>
            <th>Column 'two'</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>row one</td>
            <td>row one</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>row two</td>
            <td>row two</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the CSS:

```
tr th:first-child,
tr td:first-child {
    visibility: hidden;
    border: 0 none transparent; /* hide the borders */
    width: 1em; /* define the width, to avoid the visible content */
}               /* causing page-jumps */

tr th:first-child + th,
tr td:first-child + td {
    border-left: 2px solid #000; /* style the cell *after* the first-child */
}                                /* with a border to 'fake' the look of the */
                                 /* new content being appended outside */
td, th {
    visibility: visible;
    border: 1px solid #000;      /* show borders to continue the illusion */
    height: 2em;                 /* or whatever... */
    line-height: 2em;
}
```

This approach *seems* to work (and *should* work in IE as well, I think): [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wX9z8/3/),

Comment: I like it. Though when I change the first column's display from hidden to visible, it seems to shift the row to the right (i.e. the notification/icon appears in the first column of jqGrid instead of to the left of the table)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use jQuery's "my at of" positioning:

1) Append the element to the body of the page.

2) Use jQuery "my at of" positioning to place the element next to the row element that you're trying to mark as urgent. http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Position

Answer (score 0):

You can use afterInsertRow event from jqGrid:

```
var my_jqGrid = $('#id_table').jqGrid({
   ... //Other configs

   afterInsertRow: function(rowid, rowdata, rowelement){

       console.log(rowdata);
       //Here you code condition to insert in other div
       if(rowdata['key']=='status_ok'){
           $('#div_id').append( '<img src="image/ok.png" />'  );
       }          
   }

});
```

See the wiki [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents)

Well i append a simple image you can append a div container image and set the heigth with css.